# Dynamically passing flag to xargs

Tags: bash, shell, xargs

I have this:

```
r_flag=' -r ';

docker ps -aq  | xargs "$r_flag" docker rm -v | cat;
```

and I get this error on ubuntu:

> `xargs:  -r : No such file or directory`

why is that? I am just trying to pass the -r option to xargs. The problem seems to go a way if I change it from:

```
r_flag=' -r ';
```

to

```
r_flag='-r';
```

lame...! But why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `r_flag=" -r "` the spaces are included in the value of the variable.  In other words, the argument `"$r_flag"` to `xargs` does not start with a `-`, and is therefore not taken as an option.  An option's first character *has* to be a dash.

Since it's not an option, `xargs` interprets it as the name of the utility that it should run.  It fails to find the utility and complains.

Alternate way of doing the right thing:

```
set -- -r
docker ps -aq | xargs "$@" docker rm -v
```

Or, using an array in `bash`,

```
xargs_opts=( -r )
docker ps -aq | xargs "${xargs_opts[@]}" docker rm -v
```

This would make it easy to pass additional flags to `xargs` without having to define new variables:

```
set -- -r -t
docker ps -aq | xargs "$@" docker rm -v
```

Or, using an array in `bash`,

```
xargs_opts=( -r -t )
docker ps -aq | xargs "${xargs_opts[@]}" docker rm -v
```

The array passed to the command could obviously be constructed dynamically:

```
xargs_opts=()

if should_trace; then
    xargs_opts+=( -t )
fi
if should_not_run_on_empty; then
    xargs_opts+=( -r )
fi
```

Comment: yeah, wonder why the whitespace is interpreted as start of variable, a way to avoid that?

Comment: @AlexanderMills Not as a variable, as a non-option, an operand. Yes, you can simply avoid putting the spaces into the value of `r_flag`.

Comment: yeah the whitespaces around the flag were designed to be safe in case it's inserted like this by accident `xargs"${r_flag}"docker rm -v`  (w/o any whitespace on one side of the var etc)

Comment: @AlexanderMills I would say that that would be a programming error.  If you try that command, you will see that the shell complains about not finding the `xargs -r docker` command (it takes that whole string as the literal name of a single command).